# deploy a Spring MVC + Maven in Tomcat 7

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat, deployment

I want to **deploy a maven project based in Spring MVC into a Tomcat server**.
I have been working with eclipse + tomcat 7, in local mode, and the project work correctly, but now, i buy a host with PLESK and the app doesnt work.

I build a .WAR with maven plugin method (Goal clean install, adn JDK 1.8 compiler):
[image]

The result:
[image]

I test with a normal wep app .war file and the host work correctly, for this reason i suppouse that the problem is the structure of my proyect before build the .war file... but i dont know.

Sample.war struct:

[image]

My current structure is this (Maven project using Spring MVC) :

[image]

An the lines of my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>TreeBuk</groupId>
<artifactId>TreeBuk</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

My index.jsp and all my other views is into **WebContent/WEB-INF/views**. I saw some examples where **index.jsp** is in WebContent/WEB-INF/... but i dont know why...For other hand, i test it in local server tomcat too (no in eclipse instance) but dont work the deployment... I dont understand **why WORK into eclipse on tomcat instance, but in local tomcat server doesnt work**.

**Anybody can help me to deploy my wepApp in server? Where is the problem?**

P.D: im using Apache Tiles 3.0, some .xml configuration files (security-context.xml, persistence-context.xml, service-context, etc, into src/com.treebuk/config in addition to WebContent/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml file)

**EDIT 1**:
When start the local tomcat server executing apache-tomcat-7.0.67\bin\startip.bat I can see this in the console:
[image]

and if I go to url http://localhost:8080/TreeBuk/
[image]

**EDIT 2**
In my **web.xml** file I have configured the multi context files xml. (remind that the app works into tomcat server instance of Eclipse)

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:com/treebuk/config/persistence-context.xml
        classpath:com/treebuk/config/service-context.xml
        classpath:com/treebuk/config/security-context.xml
        classpath:com/treebuk/config/application-context.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: A small advice, use intellij idea for java project. You will be amazed with ease of doing things in intellij.

Comment: Your exception tells that, the app you build searching for a file named `persistence-context.xml` but its not exists in your class path. Did you put this file on that path?

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna of couse, i changed the config .xml files for test from src/com/treebuk/config to WEB-INF and change the classpath value to WEB-INF/persistence-context.xml.. and the information message changes for indicate that the resources doesnt find....Im trying solved this problem too... but i dont understand why work in tomcat server instance  of eclipse and other server not...

Comment: Lets put `persistence-context.xml` files in `src/com/treebuk/config` and test it. If that's ok in production mode, then try to change in step by step manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnaly, I dont know that happend, but the structure of .War was invalid... i rebuild the project in a new Spring MVC project with other valid structure and i could to generate the .war file.

Sorry but this havent a simple solution.